# arguments of one anonymous function in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I would like to know the meaning of this piece of code for find one possible bug:

```rb
-> a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j {
  l = -> s, t = c {
    Math.log(s, t)
  }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Where is this code coming from? I hope it's an example of what *not* to do in Ruby.

Comment: That is only the start of the function, it continue using all arguments...

Comment: Ouch. Has it been minified? What's the purpose of this lambda?

Comment: @EricDuminil gain one or two characters in a codegolf competition...

Comment: If it were for golfing, you could remove all the whitespaces: `->a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j{l=->s,t=c{Math.log(s,t)}}`.

Comment: I find it curious that, while this question is on hold as unclear what is being asked, it has to date received three upvotes, suggesting that at least three readers not only  understand it, but think it's a good question.  (I'm in the "have no idea" camp.)

Answer (score 5):

The first part: `-> a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j { ... }` is declaration of a lambda, or anonymous function.

where a,b,c... and so on are arguments to be passed as variables inside the block `{..}`

This is the same as: `lambda { |a,b,c,...j| ... }`

You can see a similar example here:

```
ex1 = -> a,b,c,d {
  puts a;
  puts b;
  puts c;
}

ex1.call('1', '2', '3', '4');
```

Then it returns another lambda inside of it:

l = `->` s, t = c {Math.log(s, t)

as denoted by the `->` symbol, and defaults `t` argument to previously supplied `c` arg in the outer lambda.

Finally it call Math.log on s and t arguments from the inner lambda.

Here's a simplified version:

```
ex2 = -> a,b { c = -> d, e = b { puts d; puts e } }

ex2.call(1,2).call(3) # e is optional since it's defaulted to b
# => 3,2
```

Note: Your code is missing some `}`.

Comment: For which code did you write the simplified version? It doesn't seem to match OP's code or your first example.

Comment: Simplified version of the concept, not the code itself.

Answer (score 4):

To be honest, this code is absolutely horrible. I'd be surprised to learn that there's only one bug.

Here's a rewrite:

```
weird_log = lambda do |_, _, default_base, _, _, _, _, _, _, _|
  lambda do |x, base=default_base|
    Math.log(x, base)
  end
end
```

It's a bit more readable and it makes it clear that the method signature is useless. In the original code, only `c` is used from the 10 original arguments.

`a, b, d, e, f, g, h, i, j` aren't used so they can be renamed to `_`. They need to be specified, though, even if they aren't used:

```
weird_log.call(nil, nil, 10)
#=> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 10)
weird_log.call(nil, nil, 10, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil)
#=> #<Proc:0x00000000031e57c8@(pry):9 (lambda)>
weird_log.call(nil, nil, 10, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil).call(100)
#=> 2.0
weird_log.call(nil, nil, 10, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil).call(100, Math::E)
# => 4.605170185988092
```

A less cryptic way would be to write:

```
def my_log(base = Math::E)
  ->(x) { Math.log(x, base) }
end
```

It can be used this way:

```
log10 = my_log(10)
# => #<Proc:0x000000000222d2b8@(irb):2 (lambda)> 
log10.call(100)
# => 2.0
natural_log = my_log
#=> #<Proc:0x0000000002243540@(irb):2 (lambda)>
natural_log.call(10)
#=> 2.302585092994046
```

But then, you might as well use [`Math.log`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Math.html#method-c-log) directly:

```
Math.log(100, 10)
# => 2.0
Math.log(10)
# => 2.302585092994046
```